# Heroku Schedule task with postgres connection and python

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have a web app running on heroku using flask and SQLAlchemy. I am now wondering how i can start a schedule task that runs daily and does some database related tasks (deleting some row if you need to know:)

The documentation on heroku recommends to use APScheduler but i would like to do it with Heroku-Scheduler. Dispite this decision i would like to know how i connect to my postgres database in this scheduler task. I could not find any example or hint for that.

thanks for your time
Torsten

Answer (score 3):

Heroku scheduler will run any command you throw at it. The typical way would be to create a Python script/command as part of your flask app. You can do something similar to http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. Then within the scheduler you would schedule it similar to:

```
python manage.py mytask
```